# How did Mastani die in 'Bajirao Mastani'?

Tags: plot-explanation, historical-accuracy, bajirao-mastani

In [Bajirao Mastani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bajirao_Mastani_(film)) movie, how did Mastani actually die?

We saw her under arrest! Whereas on one side Bajirao died near Narmada River and at same time she died but there is no clue what happened to her.

The film is based on a true story. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastani) says that the 'Cause of Death' might be suicide but that No documentation is available to confirm the actual cause

How did she die in movie (and in real life)? Answers for both would be appreciated.

Comment: Please consider accepting one of the answers or comment accordingly so that we will know whether you want further details.

Answer (score 3):

**Her death has been a mystery till date in real life. Same mystery is maintained in the movie.**

Rather than taking the liberty of portraying it according to the writer's/director's wish they chose not to. And I am glad they did so.

Quoting from [Advanced study in the history of modern India, 1707-1813](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=d1wUgKKzawoC&lpg=PA125&pg=PA125#v=onepage&q&f=false) (page 125):

> After the conclusion of the war, the Peshwa sent Chimanji Appa back to
> Poona while Balaji Baji Rao was deputed by him to proceed to Kolaba to
> settle the property dispute between the Angre brothers.
> The Peshwa himself retired to Raver, on the southern bank of the
> Narmada, where he was struck with 'virulent fever', and breathed his
> last on 18 April 1740. On the receipt of this sad news, Mastani died
> within a couple of days, **'whether by suicide or of shock, it is
> difficult to say'**.
>
> (Footnote: According to some, Mastani committed sati on her husband's funeral pyre.)

(Emphasis mine)

Answer (score 0):

The film may be based on a true story but at that time it was a custom to jump into pyre of dead husband (Known as [Sati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sati_%28practice%29) in India). Mastani most likely died after jumping into her husband's pyre as it was a common religious practice. In 1861 Queen Victoria banned Sati custom in whole India.

In film they must have considered this but they didn't mention how she actually died. She might have taken a poison as it would be easy to die that way than jumping into pyre.

In film they tried to convey that she drank a poison.